# Show that $X$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

given:
$X$ a linear operator on $n\times n$ matrix field
$X$ defined by $X(Y) = Y^t$

show: 
$X$ is diagonaliable

find:
eigenvaules and eigenvectors

---

my thought:

i am confused by X(Y) = Y^t part. does it mean that X maps any matrix Y to Y^t? so if i take n*n matrix Y then multiplying that with X matrix would somehow give me Y * Y *....Y (t times)?

i dunno what to do with the variable "t" either.

Comment: Can be transposition?

Answer (score 4):

Let me denote your operator $f$ so we have $f^2=\operatorname{id}$ hence the polynomial with simple roots $x^2-1$ annihilates $f$ so it's diagonalizable with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ (since $f\ne\pm\operatorname{id}$).

For the eigenvectors, notice that if $A$ is a symmetric matrix we have
$$f(A)=A$$
so $A$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $1$ and if $A$ is antisymmetric matrix then
$$f(A)=-A$$
so....

Comment: 3 questions (if you could answer them that would be great): (1) how did you get f^2 = id? (2) how did you find A to be associated eigenvalue for 1? (3) basically, f is some matrix that sends any matrix to its transpose. would it be viable to figure such matrix and find its e-value and e-vector or would that be too much of a work?

Comment: @user124994 Let me answer your three questions by three simple questions:-): What's the transpose of the transpose of a matrix $A$? What means $A$ is symmetric matrix? What's the meaning of
$$f(A)=\lambda A?$$

Comment: transpose of a transpose of matrix A is matrix A itself. symmetric means matrix A is equal to its transpose. i dunno about the third one. it looks similar to def of eigenvector but this is all so confusing. i still can't figure out how A can be eigenvector when f is operator on A and everything uhhhh

Comment: yeah i still don't get how f^2 is id either. i think i am missing some key concept. if you could explain it in simplest way that would be amazing. cheers for your time :)

Comment: @user124994 As you said that the transpose of transpose of a matrix $A$ is $A$ itself so we have $f\circ f= \operatorname{id}$ and since the transpose of a symmetric matrix $A$ is $A$ then we have $f(A)=A$ and $$f(A)=\lambda A$$ means that $A$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: ha thanks. i was just starting at it. i guess i need to refresh my knowledge of mapping/e-vector. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

A basis of $X$ is $\{E_{ij}\}_{i,j=1}^n$ - $E_{ij}$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with zeros everywhere except of the $(i,j)$-place, where it has an $1$, i.e.,
$$
A=(a_{ij})=\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}E_{ij}.
$$

We note that
$$
f(E_{ij})=E_{ji},
$$
which allows us to diagonalize $f$ as follows
$$
f(E_{ii})=E_{ii}, \quad i=1,\ldots,n,
$$
$$
f(E_{ij}+E_{ji})=E_{ij}+E_{ji}, \quad 1\le i<j\le n,
$$
and
$$
f(E_{ij}-E_{ji})=-(E_{ij}+E_{ji}), \quad 1\le i<j\le n.
$$
Altogether $n^2$ eigenvectors.